# Can’t fix pyparsing error…

Tags: python, parsing, testing, pyparsing

## Overview

So, I’m in the middle of refactoring a project, and I’m separating out a bunch of parsing code.  The code I’m concerned with is pyparsing.

I have a very poor understanding of pyparsing, even after spending a lot of time reading through the official documentation.  I’m having trouble because (1) pyparsing takes a (deliberately) unorthodox approach to parsing, and (2) I’m working on code I didn’t write, with poor comments, and a non-elementary set of existing grammars.

(I can’t get in touch with the original author, either.)

### Failing Test

I’m using [PyVows](http://heynemann.github.com/pyvows/) to test my code.  One of my tests is as follows (I think this is clear even if you’re unfamiliar with PyVows; let me know if it isn’t):

```py
def test_multiline_command_ends(self, topic):
                output = parsed_input('multiline command ends\n\n',topic)
                expect(output).to_equal(
r'''['multiline', 'command ends', '\n', '\n']
- args: command ends
- multiline_command: multiline
- statement: ['multiline', 'command ends', '\n', '\n']
  - args: command ends
  - multiline_command: multiline
  - terminator: ['\n', '\n']
- terminator: ['\n', '\n']''')
```

But when I run the test, I get the following in the terminal:

#### Failed Test Results

```py
Expected topic("['multiline', 'command ends']\n- args: command ends\n- command: multiline\n- statement: ['multiline', 'command ends']\n  - args: command ends\n  - command: multiline") 
      to equal "['multiline', 'command ends', '\\n', '\\n']\n- args: command ends\n- multiline_command: multiline\n- statement: ['multiline', 'command ends', '\\n', '\\n']\n  - args: command ends\n  - multiline_command: multiline\n  - terminator: ['\\n', '\\n']\n- terminator: ['\\n', '\\n']"
```

**Note:**

Since the output is to a Terminal, the expected output (the second one) has extra backslashes.  This is normal. The test ran without issue before this piece of refactoring began.

### Expected Behavior

The first line of output should match the second, but it doesn’t.  Specifically, it’s not including the two newline characters in that first list object.

So I’m getting this:

```py
"['multiline', 'command ends']\n- args: command ends\n- command: multiline\n- statement: ['multiline', 'command ends']\n  - args: command ends\n  - command: multiline"
```

When I **should** be getting this:

```py
"['multiline', 'command ends', '\\n', '\\n']\n- args: command ends\n- multiline_command: multiline\n- statement: ['multiline', 'command ends', '\\n', '\\n']\n  - args: command ends\n  - multiline_command: multiline\n  - terminator: ['\\n', '\\n']\n- terminator: ['\\n', '\\n']"
```

Earlier in the code, there is also this statement:

```py
pyparsing.ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' \t')
```

…Which I *think* should prevent exactly this kind of error.  But I’m not sure.

Even if the problem can’t be identified with certainty, simply narrowing down where the problem is would be a HUGE help.

Please let me know how I might take a step or two towards fixing this.

---

**Edit:** So, uh, I should post the parser code for this, shouldn’t I?  (Thanks for the tip, @andrew cooke !)

## Parser code

Here’s the `__init__` for my parser object.

I **know** it’s  a nightmare.  That’s why I’m refactoring the project. ☺

```py
def __init__(self, Cmd_object=None, *args, **kwargs):
        #   @NOTE
        #   This is one of the biggest pain points of the existing code.
        #   To aid in readability, I CAPITALIZED all variables that are
        #   not set on `self`.
        #
        #   That means that CAPITALIZED variables aren't
        #   used outside of this method.
        #
        #   Doing this has allowed me to more easily read what
        #   variables become a part of other variables during the
        #   building-up of the various parsers.
        #
        #   I realize the capitalized variables is unorthodox
        #   and potentially anti-convention.  But after reaching out
        #   to the project's creator several times over roughly 5
        #   months, I'm still working on this project alone...
        #   And without help, this is the only way I can move forward.
        #
        #   I have a very poor understanding of the parser's
        #   control flow when the user types a command and hits ENTER,
        #   and until the author (or another pyparsing expert)
        #   explains what's happening to me, I have to do silly
        #   things like this. :-|
        #
        #   Of course, if the impossible happens and this code
        #   gets cleaned up, then the variables will be restored to
        #   proper capitalization.
        #
        #   —Zearin
        #   http://github.com/zearin/
        #   2012 Mar 26

        if Cmd_object is not None:
            self.Cmd_object = Cmd_object
        else:
            raise Exception('Cmd_object be provided to Parser.__init__().')

        #   @FIXME
        #       Refactor methods into this class later
        preparse    = self.Cmd_object.preparse
        postparse   = self.Cmd_object.postparse

        self._allow_blank_lines  =  False

        self.abbrev              =  True       # Recognize abbreviated commands
        self.case_insensitive    =  True       # Commands recognized regardless of case
        # make sure your terminators are not in legal_chars!
        self.legal_chars         =  u'!#$%.:?@_' + PYP.alphanums + PYP.alphas8bit
        self.multiln_commands    =  [] if 'multiline_commands' not in kwargs else kwargs['multiln_commands']
        self.no_special_parse    =  {'ed','edit','exit','set'}
        self.redirector          =  '>'         # for sending output to file
        self.reserved_words      =  []
        self.shortcuts           =  { '?' : 'help' ,
                                      '!' : 'shell',
                                      '@' : 'load' ,
                                      '@@': '_relative_load'
                                    }
#         self._init_grammars()
#         
#     def _init_grammars(self):
        #   @FIXME
        #       Add Docstring

        #   ----------------------------
        #   Tell PYP how to parse
        #   file input from '< filename'
        #   ----------------------------
        FILENAME    = PYP.Word(self.legal_chars + '/\\')
        INPUT_MARK  = PYP.Literal('<')
        INPUT_MARK.setParseAction(lambda x: '')
        INPUT_FROM  = FILENAME('INPUT_FROM')
        INPUT_FROM.setParseAction( self.Cmd_object.replace_with_file_contents )
        #   ----------------------------

        #OUTPUT_PARSER = (PYP.Literal('>>') | (PYP.WordStart() + '>') | PYP.Regex('[^=]>'))('output')
        OUTPUT_PARSER           =  (PYP.Literal(   2 * self.redirector) | \
                                   (PYP.WordStart()  + self.redirector) | \
                                    PYP.Regex('[^=]' + self.redirector))('output')

        PIPE                    =   PYP.Keyword('|', identChars='|')

        STRING_END              =   PYP.stringEnd ^ '\nEOF'

        TERMINATORS             =  [';']
        TERMINATOR_PARSER       =   PYP.Or([
                                        (hasattr(t, 'parseString') and t)
                                        or 
                                        PYP.Literal(t) for t in TERMINATORS
                                    ])('terminator')

        self.comment_grammars    =  PYP.Or([  PYP.pythonStyleComment,
                                              PYP.cStyleComment ])
        self.comment_grammars.ignore(PYP.quotedString)
        self.comment_grammars.setParseAction(lambda x: '')
        self.comment_grammars.addParseAction(lambda x: '')

        self.comment_in_progress =  '/*' + PYP.SkipTo(PYP.stringEnd ^ '*/')

        #   QuickRef: Pyparsing Operators
        #   ----------------------------
        #   ~   creates NotAny using the expression after the operator
        #
        #   +   creates And using the expressions before and after the operator
        #
        #   |   creates MatchFirst (first left-to-right match) using the
        #       expressions before and after the operator
        #
        #   ^   creates Or (longest match) using the expressions before and
        #       after the operator
        #
        #   &   creates Each using the expressions before and after the operator
        #
        #   *   creates And by multiplying the expression by the integer operand;
        #       if expression is multiplied by a 2-tuple, creates an And of
        #       (min,max) expressions (similar to "{min,max}" form in
        #       regular expressions); if min is None, intepret as (0,max);
        #       if max is None, interpret as expr*min + ZeroOrMore(expr)
        #
        #   -   like + but with no backup and retry of alternatives
        #
        #   *   repetition of expression
        #
        #   ==  matching expression to string; returns True if the string
        #       matches the given expression
        #
        #   <<  inserts the expression following the operator as the body of the
        #       Forward expression before the operator
        #   ----------------------------


        DO_NOT_PARSE            =   self.comment_grammars       |   \
                                    self.comment_in_progress    |   \
                                    PYP.quotedString

        #   moved here from class-level variable
        self.URLRE              =   re.compile('(https?://[-\\w\\./]+)')

        self.keywords           =   self.reserved_words + [fname[3:] for fname in dir( self.Cmd_object ) if fname.startswith('do_')]

        #   not to be confused with `multiln_parser` (below)
        self.multiln_command  =   PYP.Or([
                                        PYP.Keyword(c, caseless=self.case_insensitive)
                                        for c in self.multiln_commands
                                    ])('multiline_command')

        ONELN_COMMAND           =   (   ~self.multiln_command +
                                        PYP.Word(self.legal_chars)
                                    )('command')


        #self.multiln_command.setDebug(True)


        #   Configure according to `allow_blank_lines` setting
        if self._allow_blank_lines:
            self.blankln_termination_parser = PYP.NoMatch
        else:
            BLANKLN_TERMINATOR  = (2 * PYP.lineEnd)('terminator')
            #BLANKLN_TERMINATOR('terminator')
            self.blankln_termination_parser = (
                                                (self.multiln_command ^ ONELN_COMMAND)
                                                + PYP.SkipTo(
                                                    BLANKLN_TERMINATOR,
                                                    ignore=DO_NOT_PARSE
                                                ).setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].strip())('args')
                                                + BLANKLN_TERMINATOR
                                              )('statement')

        #   CASE SENSITIVITY for
        #   ONELN_COMMAND and self.multiln_command
        if self.case_insensitive:
            #   Set parsers to account for case insensitivity (if appropriate)
            self.multiln_command.setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].lower())
            ONELN_COMMAND.setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].lower())


        self.save_parser        = ( PYP.Optional(PYP.Word(PYP.nums)^'*')('idx')
                                  + PYP.Optional(PYP.Word(self.legal_chars + '/\\'))('fname')
                                  + PYP.stringEnd)

        AFTER_ELEMENTS          =   PYP.Optional(PIPE +
                                                    PYP.SkipTo(
                                                        OUTPUT_PARSER ^ STRING_END,
                                                        ignore=DO_NOT_PARSE
                                                    )('pipeTo')
                                                ) + \
                                    PYP.Optional(OUTPUT_PARSER +
                                                 PYP.SkipTo(
                                                     STRING_END,
                                                     ignore=DO_NOT_PARSE
                                                 ).setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].strip())('outputTo')
                                            )

        self.multiln_parser = (((self.multiln_command ^ ONELN_COMMAND)
                                +   PYP.SkipTo(
                                        TERMINATOR_PARSER,
                                        ignore=DO_NOT_PARSE
                                    ).setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].strip())('args')
                                +   TERMINATOR_PARSER)('statement')
                                +   PYP.SkipTo(
                                        OUTPUT_PARSER ^ PIPE ^ STRING_END,
                                        ignore=DO_NOT_PARSE
                                    ).setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].strip())('suffix')
                                + AFTER_ELEMENTS
                             )

        #self.multiln_parser.setDebug(True)

        self.multiln_parser.ignore(self.comment_in_progress)

        self.singleln_parser  = (
                                    (   ONELN_COMMAND + PYP.SkipTo(
                                        TERMINATOR_PARSER
                                        ^ STRING_END
                                        ^ PIPE
                                        ^ OUTPUT_PARSER,
                                        ignore=DO_NOT_PARSE
                                    ).setParseAction(lambda x:x[0].strip())('args'))('statement')
                                + PYP.Optional(TERMINATOR_PARSER)
                                + AFTER_ELEMENTS)
        #self.multiln_parser  = self.multiln_parser('multiln_parser')
        #self.singleln_parser = self.singleln_parser('singleln_parser')

        self.prefix_parser       =  PYP.Empty()

        self.parser = self.prefix_parser + (STRING_END                      |
                                            self.multiln_parser             |
                                            self.singleln_parser            |
                                            self.blankln_termination_parser |
                                            self.multiln_command            +
                                            PYP.SkipTo(
                                                STRING_END,
                                                ignore=DO_NOT_PARSE)
                                            )

        self.parser.ignore(self.comment_grammars)

        # a not-entirely-satisfactory way of distinguishing
        # '<' as in "import from" from
        # '<' as in "lesser than"
        self.input_parser = INPUT_MARK                + \
                            PYP.Optional(INPUT_FROM)  + \
                            PYP.Optional('>')         + \
                            PYP.Optional(FILENAME)    + \
                            (PYP.stringEnd | '|')

        self.input_parser.ignore(self.comment_in_progress)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## I fixed it!

Pyparsing was not at fault!

I was.  ☹

By separating out the parsing code into a different object, I created the problem.  Originally, an attribute used to “update itself” based on the contents of a second attribute.  Since this all used to be contained in one “god class”, it worked fine.

Simply by separating the code into another object, the first attribute was set at instantiation, but no longer “updated itself” if the second attribute it depended on changed.

### Specifics

The attribute `multiln_command` (not to be confused with `multiln_commands`—aargh, what confusing naming!) was a pyparsing grammar definition. The `multiln_command` attribute should have updated its grammar if `multiln_commands` ever changed.

Although I knew these two attributes had similar names but very different purposes, the similarity definitely made it harder to track the problem down.  I have no renamed `multiln_command` to `multiln_grammar`.

## However! ☺

I am grateful to @Paul McGuire’s awesome answer, and I hope it saves me (and others) some grief in the future.  Although I feel a bit foolish that I caused the problem (and misdiagnosed it as a pyparsing issue), I’m happy some good (in the form of Paul’s advice) came of asking this question.

---

Happy parsing, everybody. :)

Comment: In pyparsing 3.0, calling `setDefaultWhitespaceChars` will update whitespace chars for all pyparsing defined helppers also.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that the problem is pyparsing's builtin whitespace skipping, which will skip over newlines by default. Even though `setDefaultWhitespaceChars` is used to tell pyparsing that newlines are significant, this setting only affects all expressions that are created *after* the call to `setDefaultWhitespaceChars`. The problem is that pyparsing tries to help by defining a number of convenience expressions when it is imported, like `empty` for `Empty()`, `lineEnd` for `LineEnd()` and so on. But since these are all created at import time, they are defined with the original default whitespace characters, which include `'\n'`.

I should probably just do this in `setDefaultWhitespaceChars`, but you can clean this up for yourself too.  Right after calling `setDefaultWhitespaceChars`, redefine these module-level expressions in pyparsing:

```
PYP.ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' \t')
# redefine module-level constants to use new default whitespace chars
PYP.empty = PYP.Empty()
PYP.lineEnd = PYP.LineEnd()
PYP.stringEnd = PYP.StringEnd()
```

I think this will help restore the significance of your embedded newlines.

Some other bits on your parser code:

```
        self.blankln_termination_parser = PYP.NoMatch
```

should be

```
        self.blankln_termination_parser = PYP.NoMatch()
```

Your original author might have been overly aggressive with using '^' over '|'. Only use '^' if there is some potential for parsing one expression accidentally when you would really have parsed a longer one that follows later in the list of alternatives.  For instance, in:

```
    self.save_parser        = ( PYP.Optional(PYP.Word(PYP.nums)^'*')('idx')
```

There is no possible confusion between a Word of numeric digits or a lone `'*'`.  `Or` (or `'^'` operator) tells pyparsing to try to evaluate all of the alternatives, and then pick the longest matching one - in case of a tie, chose the left-most alternative in the list.  If you parse `'*'`, there is no need to see if that might also match a longer integer, or if you parse an integer, no need to see if it might also pass as a lone `'*'`.  So change this to:

```
    self.save_parser        = ( PYP.Optional(PYP.Word(PYP.nums)|'*')('idx')
```

Using a parse action to replace a string with '' is more simply written using a `PYP.Suppress` wrapper, or if you prefer, call `expr.suppress()` which returns `Suppress(expr)`.  Combined with preference for '|' over '^', this:

```
    self.comment_grammars    =  PYP.Or([  PYP.pythonStyleComment, 
                                          PYP.cStyleComment ]) 
    self.comment_grammars.ignore(PYP.quotedString) 
    self.comment_grammars.setParseAction(lambda x: '')
```

becomse:

```
    self.comment_grammars    =  (PYP.pythonStyleComment | PYP.cStyleComment
                                ).ignore(PYP.quotedString).suppress()
```

Keywords have built-in logic to automatically avoid ambiguity, so Or is completely unnecessary with them:

```
    self.multiln_command  =   PYP.Or([ 
                                    PYP.Keyword(c, caseless=self.case_insensitive) 
                                    for c in self.multiln_commands 
                                ])('multiline_command')
```

should be:

```
    self.multiln_command  =   PYP.MatchFirst([
                                    PYP.Keyword(c, caseless=self.case_insensitive) 
                                    for c in self.multiln_commands 
                                ])('multiline_command')
```

(In the next release, I'll loosen up those initializers to accept generator expressions so that the []'s will become unnecessary.)

That's all I can see for now. Hope this helps.

Comment: Whoa!  Paul McGuire, father of pyparsing. ☺  Thank you for the *extraordinary* help!  I’m going to try this out right away… :)

Comment: P.S.: One quick question: this code was split out of a main file.  (It used to be a one-file module, and I’m turning it into a multi-module package.)  Back when all the code was in one file, the test was running correctly.  It’s not really important at this point, but I’m curious…what might be the difference that broke the test?

Comment: This is purely speculation, as there shouldn't normally be any issue with splitting code out into multiple files if the imports are kept straight. But if you have references to constants defined at module scope in the original file, and then split them out into a separate file, you may have erroneously "fixed" the reference problem by defining a new local variable. You may have implemented it incorrectly, OR the module-level variable contains some mutable state that was formerly shared across the single module, but is now local to your local copy.

Comment: One other tip: write down the BNF for this grammar. It will help you to better understand just what the target was that the original author was going for, it will organize your own thinking better, give you a roadmap to the parser, and help you keep straight where changes should go if you need to add new syntax features or fix bugs in the existing one.

Comment: And one last pyparsing tip: you can peek into the workings of the parser if you mark some key expressions with `setDebug()`. Debug-enabled expressions will report when they are about to try parsing, and the if they failed or succeeded, and if succeeded, what the matching text was. `setName()` is also useful when using `setDebug`, as you can give the expression a meaningful name, like `integer = Word(nums).setName('integer')` then when it reports in debug, you'll see that you are matching 'integer', not 'W:(0123...)'.